# Change ImageView to TextView in GridView based on user input

Tags: java, android, xml, gridview, imageview

I am developing an android app as an educational project. I have created a GridView object, which uses a custom GridAdapter. The grid, as default, loads a set of placeholder images. I want the user to be able to replace those placeholder images with either their own image, some text, or a link to a youtube video.

I can't find any info on whether this is feasible. I specify an Imageview in my XML file, so I don't know how I could change this at run time? I wondered if I should create a TextView object in the XML, and layer them, and then create a method that brings one to the front? Any advice at all would be very much appreciated. It would be great to know if it's doable or not.....

```
  <ImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/imageView"
    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
    />
```

Comment: I guess you could specify both the ImageView stub and a container for an actual content that will be chosen by the user. Then declare the stub visible & the container gone in the xml. 
In the runtime when it's necessary just make the container with the content visible and the stub gone.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My suggestion is define `TextView` etc. in xml with `gone` visibility. When user has some actions get `visible` them and set visibility `gone` of `ImageView`.

Answer (score 1):

Set the visibilities of the container based  on user input... What ever user chooses make tat container visible and other two as Gone... This would work